# Checkout subdirectory in Git

Tags: git

I try to checkout only a subdirectory from my local git-Repro because the Repro contains the server-code and the ui-code like this structure:

```
/[repro:branchname]
  /[ServiceCode(SelfhostedWCFService)]
  /[UI-Code(ASPX)]
  /...
```

and repro has branches.

Now i try to checkout ONLY the UI-Code (ASP.Net-Pages) to a different directory, run under IIS and make changes and the i will commit this changes to the branche.

In SVN i checkout the subdirectory, make my changes, commit and finish. How can i do this with git?

Remark: The git-Repro is an git-svn-clone from my company-repro with (for historical reasons) many subfolders and subprojects there are not seperate repros. The target subdirectory is a network-drive on a other machine so i can set links.

Comment: possible, but i din't understand how to do this. I have read many tutorial's about this.

Comment: What part has confused you?

Comment: i always get an error: "'d:\repro\uicode\' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: Have you done `git init` in that directory?

Comment: if have execute "git config core.sparsecheckout true" on "d:\repro"

Comment: yes, i habe do "git init" in the target directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44624/discussion-between-floyd-and-chris)

Comment: I will be back in that chat room today, if you want to try again.